# Unity3D - What does child object inherit from its parent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What does child object inherit from its parent in Unity except transform (when parent object is moved, then children are being moved too)?

Comment: I am also interested. I think the transform (position,rotation..) is the only component to be "guaranteed" to be in common. So my guess, its just this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity's inheritance isn't like pure OOP inheritance. It's not like a base class provides virtual members that a child inherits.

In Unity a child object *inherits* only the [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). It doesn't really inherit it, it just becomes the base for it's own Transform component therefore when modifying the child component it will be relative to the parent. Since all object by default need to at least have only 1 component (Transform) that's pretty much all that can be inherited by a child object.

Answer (score 3):

The child will not inherit the parents transform directly, rather the childs transform becomes relative to that of the parent. So if we take the example of the transforms position, a GameObject without a parent will be relative to the world coordinates, whereas a GameObject with a parent will be relative to the parents position. You can get the relative position using [localPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html), which will be equal to the `Transform.position` if the GameObject has no parents.

As a more concrete example (I'll use 2D coordinates for simplicity):

Say we have a GameObject (A) at world position (0,0) without any parents. Its `Transform.position` will be (0,0) and `Transform.localPosition` will also be (0,0).

If we add another GameObject (B), make it a child of A and set its world position to be (1,0) then its `Transform.position` and `Transform.localPosition` will both be (1,0).

Now if we were to move GameObject A to (2,0), we would see that B would move to (3,0) in world space, but its `Transform.localPosition` would still be (1,0) as this is relative to the position of A.

The child won't inherit anything else from the parent, though the relationship can be used in code to obtain references to each other via [`Transform.parent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) and [`Transform.GetChild`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html).